# CSS vertical alignment and floating issue

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I'm creating a website which enables reservation of hour-long blocks. I'm trying to get the style right.

This is what it should look like:

[image]

And here is the code I've written so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
            font-weight: 300;
            margin-left: 25px;
            margin-right: 25px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        #header
        {
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .block
        {
            background-color: #e5e5e5;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 275px;
            height: 35px;
        }
        .block-sideline
        {
            background-color: #999999;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 5px;
            width: 5px;
            height: 35px;
        }
        .block-span
        {
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
        .block-hours
        {
            color: #000000;
        }
        .block-status
        {
        }
        .block-notavailable .block-sideline
        {
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <img id="header-logo" src="header-logo.svg" height="50px" width="125px" />
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h2>Sunday, December 1, 2013</h2>
        <div class="block">
            <div class="block-sideline">
            </div>
            <span class="block-hours">6:00 AM &ndash; 7:00 AM</span>
            <span class="block-status">Not available</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Right now, this is what it looks like in IE:

[image]

So, now, when I float the hours and the sideline left with `float: left;` and the status right with `float: right;`, it looks like this:

[image]

Right now the margins and colors are not important, but how can I center the text inside the `div` and allow it to float at the same time? Also, in the screenshot above, the margins are not showing on the right side. Why is this?

Comment: The easiest way is by using a `line-height` equal to the height of `.block` - http://jsfiddle.net/d2epj/ - though if the height is dynamic or there is more than one line of text it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS

```
.block-sideline
{
    background-color: #999999;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 35px;
    float:left;
}
.block-hours
{
    float:left; 
    line-height:225%;
    color: #000000;
}

.block-status
{
    float:right;
    line-height:225%;
}
```

Basically add floats and line-height.